# Why do I get "IndexError: string index out of range"?

Tags: python

I'm currently a beginner to python and coding in general.

I am doing this quiz online which tasks you to remove signs (*_`~) from the front and end of a string. Eg.(~~hidden ~ tilde~~ will be changed to hidden ~ tilde) keeping the sign in the middle.

This is my code:

```
string = input()
signs = " *_`~ "
for sign in string:
    if sign in signs:
        if sign == string[0]:
            string = string.lstrip(sign)
            string = string.rstrip(sign)
print(string)
```

Which gets this error: IndexError: string index out of range

I'm just a noob trying to get started on python..plz help :(

Comment: Think about what string[0] does. What will happen if string = ""?

Comment: Note that you're assigning string=...
String is a module that you won't want to override in most cases.
Also, you're changing string during iteration, which is a bad thing.

Answer (score 5):

The entire code is unneccessary. Just use strip

```
signs = " *_`~ "
string = "*fo * o*"
print(string.strip(signs)) # fo * o
```